# How to deploy mezzanine on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, django-cms, mezzanine

I have created a mezzanine project and its name is mezzanine-heroku-test
I create a Procfile that has the content as follow:

**web: python manage.py run_gunicorn -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" -w 3**

Next, I access to the website to test and I receive the error: Internal Server Error.
So, Could you please help me deploy mezzanine on heroku step by step or some suggestion?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to see the error in the logs which you can get to using the heroku tool.

```
heroku logs
```

Answer (score 0):

These are both thorough.

https://gist.github.com/joshfinnie/4046138
http://www.benhavilland.com/blog/deploying-mezzanine-on-heroku/

This is a challenging process.