# Django [Mezzanine CMS] project not deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, mezzanine, procfile

New to Python, and trying to deploy a blog. I followed along to Heorku's documentation about [Getting Started with Python on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python). And it mentioned that I needed to add a `Procfile`, so I added the

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn hello:app
```

Did the commit, but ran into this error when attempting to deploy my app to heroku

```
Juan-Gallardos-MacBook-Pro:yatumblrgraffiti juangallardo$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 23, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (23/23), 15.50 KiB, done.
Total 23 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.4)
-----> Installing Distribute (0.6.36)
-----> Installing Pip (1.3.1)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
       Downloading/unpacking Django==1.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

       Downloading/unpacking Mezzanine==1.4.14 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Mezzanine

       Downloading/unpacking Pillow==2.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Pillow

           warning: no files found matching 'COPYING'
           warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
           warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'docs'
           warning: no files found matching 'README' under directory 'docs'
           warning: no files found matching 'CHANGES' under directory 'docs'
           warning: no files found matching 'CONTENTS' under directory 'docs'
       Downloading/unpacking PyRSS2Gen==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
         Downloading PyRSS2Gen-1.0.0.tar.gz
         Running setup.py egg_info for package PyRSS2Gen

       Downloading/unpacking Twisted==11.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Twisted

       Downloading/unpacking altgraph==0.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
         Downloading altgraph-0.7.2.tar.gz
         Running setup.py egg_info for package altgraph

           warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
       Downloading/unpacking bdist-mpkg==0.4.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading bdist_mpkg-0.4.4.tar.gz
         Running setup.py egg_info for package bdist-mpkg

       Downloading/unpacking bleach==1.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
         Downloading bleach-1.2.2.tar.gz
         Running setup.py egg_info for package bleach

       Downloading/unpacking bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
         Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
       No distributions at all found for bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:yatumblrgraffiti.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:yatumblrgraffiti.git'
```

When I ran `heroku logs` I got this

```
Juan-Gallardos-MacBook-Pro:yatumblrgraffiti juangallardo$ heroku logs
2013-09-25T06:48:50+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-09-25T06:49:16+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2013-09-25T06:56:42.862309+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=yatumblrgraffiti.herokuapp.com fwd="98.189.25.230" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-09-25T06:56:42.221149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=yatumblrgraffiti.herokuapp.com fwd="98.189.25.230" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-09-25T06:56:42.775650+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=yatumblrgraffiti.herokuapp.com fwd="98.189.25.230" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-09-25T07:00:59+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-09-25T07:01:51+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2013-09-26T04:19:23+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-09-26T04:19:48+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
```

Not a duplicate of [How to deploy mezzanine on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283628/how-to-deploy-mezzanine-on-heroku) because that question has a different Procfile and did not include his error logs.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heroku myself, but if you can't figure out an answer here and you haven't already done so I would highly recommend posting to the Mezzanine Google group.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mezzanine-users

Comment: I asked a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737960/difficult-time-using-mezzanine-on-heroku-issues-with-procfile-and-dictionary-v which may be of use to you? I hope somebody helps you out. I can't figure out why procfile just keeps not working.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with `altgraph==0.7.1` package, so just update your `requirements.txt` to point to `altgraph==0.7.2` or higher.

Source: Release history https://pypi.python.org/pypi/altgraph/

Comment: Thanks, your answer did get me closer. Question details edited.

Answer (score 0):

The package identified as bonjour-py can't be found.

```
pip search bonjour
```

Shows package name to be

```
pybonjour
```

Run

```
pip install pybonjour
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

then commit and push up to Heroku again.

Additionally, your prior issues with altgraph suggest that you may want to do a

```
pip install -U <packagename>
```

For all of your packages before pushing a new requirements.txt

If you want to take a look at your currently used package versions do a

```
pip freeze
```